# How to display timerange inside datetimepicker?

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I am struggling with an issue inside datetimepicker plugin. As I need to allow users to select a date with some time range. For example:

```
2019/08/29 07:30 - 08:30
```

But my current implementation allow me to select datetime as `2019/08/29 07:30` only. 
Below is my Jquery code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  text_12 = '07:30';
  $('#quote_pre_order_date').datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm a',
     allowTimes:[
       '07:30', '08:00','08:30', '09:00','09:30',
       '10:00','10:30', '11:00','11:30', '12:00','12:30', '13:00','13:30', '14:00'
     ],
     minDate: date,
     maxDate: someDate,
     useCurrent: false,
     defaultTime: text_12,
     icons: {

      up: "fa fa-chevron-circle-up",
      down: "fa fa-chevron-circle-down",
      next: 'fa fa-chevron-circle-right',
      previous: 'fa fa-chevron-circle-left'
    },
     disabledWeekDays: [0]
  });
</script>
```

And below is how my current datetimepicker is looks: 
[image]

But I want to display the time format as `07:30 - 08:30`. I tried a lot of ways but didn't get success. Please help if anyone can or It will also better if you can suggest some plugin which can solve my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For your use case I would use the [jQuery UI Timepicker](https://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/) plugin:

> This is a jQuery UI time picker plugin built to match with other
>   official jQuery UI widgets. Based on the existing date picker, it will
>   blend nicely with your form and use your selected jQuery UI theme. The
>   plugin is very easy to integrate in your form for time (hours /
>   minutes) inputs.

There is an example which match your use case of utilizing a **time range** using two instances of the plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#timepicker_start').timepicker({
       showLeadingZero: false,
       onSelect: tpStartSelect,
       maxTime: {
           hour: 7, minute: 30
       }
   });
   $('#timepicker_end').timepicker({
       showLeadingZero: false,
       onSelect: tpEndSelect,
       minTime: {
           hour: 14, minute: 30
       }
   });
});

// when start time change, update minimum for end timepicker
function tpStartSelect( time, endTimePickerInst ) {
   $('#timepicker_end').timepicker('option', {
       minTime: {
           hour: endTimePickerInst.hours,
           minute: endTimePickerInst.minutes
       }
   });
}

// when end time change, update maximum for start timepicker
function tpEndSelect( time, startTimePickerInst ) {
   $('#timepicker_start').timepicker('option', {
       maxTime: {
           hour: startTimePickerInst.hours,
           minute: startTimePickerInst.minutes
       }
   });
}
```